# Append string at the end of each line in a file with sed causes unquoted newline error

Tags: python, postgresql, sed, psql

I am trying to append job_id field to a CSV file prior to loading to Postgres using psql. This shall be executed within a Python script.

```
cmd = f""" \
psql {con} -c "\COPY raw.{tablename} FROM PROGRAM 'sed ''s/.*/&,\"{job_id}\"/'' /airflow/stage/test-{job_id}/{filename}' HEADER CSV"
"""

result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash', stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Above resulted in the following logged error.

```
[2021-06-27 00:35:08,527] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO -         psql postgres://user:password@10.0.0.15:5432/test -c "\COPY raw.testdata FROM PROGRAM 'sed ''s/.*/&,"20210626T155818"/'' /airflow/stage/test-20210626T155818/testdata.csv' HEADER CSV"
[2021-06-27 00:35:08,568] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - ERROR:  unquoted newline found in data
HINT:  Use quoted CSV field to represent newline.
```

Loading the file without the string append operation above would be successful. What is the correct way to append a string to each line without affecting newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file uses the DOS line ending convention of having `cr-lf` pair at the end if each line.  `\COPY` deals with this fine as long as it is consistent, but `sed` does not.  It converts your file so that the job_id is inserted in between the `cr` and the `lf`.

Comment: sorted it out with dos2unix pre-processing. thanks for answering fast enough before the question got closed.